# Second NSLog message won't print

Tags: objective-c

For some reason I can't get the second NSLog message to output to the console. Have looked for the problem, but can't find it. Thanks in advance.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  @autoreleasepool {

     // Create the array of strings to devowelize and a container for new ones
    NSArray *oldStrings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sauerkraut", @"Raygun", @"Big Nerd Ranch", @"Mississippi", nil];
    NSLog(@"old strings: %@", oldStrings);
    NSMutableArray *newStrings = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Create a list of characters that we'll remove from the string
    NSArray *vowels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"e", @"i", @"o", @"u", nil];

    // Declare the block variable
    void(^devowelizer)(id, NSUInteger, BOOL *);

    // Assign a block to the variable
    devowelizer = ^(id string, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop)
    {
      NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:string];
      // Iterate over the array of vowels, replacing occurences of each with 
      // an empty string
      for (NSString *s in vowels) {
        NSRange fullRange = NSMakeRange(0, [newString length]);
                             [newString replaceOccurrencesOfString:s 
                                                        withString:@"" 
                                                           options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
                                                             range:fullRange];
                             [newStrings addObject:newString];
                             }; //End of block assignment

      // Iterate over the array with our block
      [oldStrings enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:devowelizer];
      NSLog(@"new strings: %@", newStrings);

  };
    return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are never calling the devowelizer block. Thus, the second NSLog can never execute.

Comment: this is the correct answer, the block `devolwelizer` never called. you just defined the block and that is it, the block cannot be executed by itself.

Comment: Don't understand; aren't I passing in the block with the line: [oldStrings enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:devowelizer]; ?

Comment: That line is passing in the block, but that line will only execute if the block executes. Think of this as writing a function and then calling that function within itself. The function will only get called in the first place if something outside of the function calls it.

Comment: That line is *within* your block declaration! :)

Answer (score 1):

You created a block and assigned it to `devowelizer`. It looks like you've put your call to that block *inside* the block, which won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"new strings: %@", newStrings);
```

this line work inside the block also. You didn't call the block *devowelizer* thats what its not working.